# Titanium BlurView not recognized

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In the documentation I found that there is a BluView object that can be added to blur views: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.BlurView

When I try using it:

```
var blur = Ti.UI.iOS.createBlurView({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
});
$.test.add(blur);
```

I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] :  TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Ti.UI.iOS.createBlurView({
[ERROR] :          width: Ti.UI.FILL,
[ERROR] :          height: Ti.UI.FILL
[ERROR] :      })')
[ERROR] :  File: app.js
[ERROR] :  Line: 302
[ERROR] :  SourceId: <null>
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :   undefined
```

Is this API wrongfully documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, API docs are not wrong, but you missed one thing that the supported SDK is 5.4.0 - iPhone & iPad, and this SDK is not yet available as a General Release.

So wait until it releases or the same implementation can be achieved by using this [Apaladini blur Module](https://github.com/adrianopaladini/Live-blurView).

The docs of this above Apaladini blur module tells you how to create a blur view in iOS using controller file, but here is how you can do it using Alloy.

```
<View module="com.apaladini.blur" method="createView" style="0" width="100" height="100"></View>
```

- *style* property can be given these values:-

  - ***0 for Dark, 1 (default) for Light and 2 for ExtraLight***
- Note that the ***style*** property of this module is exactly same as  the ***effect*** property of the BlurView in API docs.

***A more useful blur module for iOS & Android : [Android+iOS Blur Module](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.BlurView)***

Good Luck!!!